# Две одинаковые таблицы, на одной странице, работают не корректно из-за JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста с javascript

При наведении мышки на один из пункт таблицы она подсвечивается по горизонтали и вертикали, я хочу разметить на одной странице восемь таких таблиц. Но увы последующие вторя, третья итд.. подсвечивается только по горизонтали.

Корни растут из этого значения "colgroup" 
Я не понимаю Java по этому не знаю что нужно прописать что бы этот вид таблиц корректно работал в количестве 2-8штук на одной странице. стоит удалить вторую таблицу как первая начинает нормально работать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [Вот ссылка на саму таблицу](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwEjZp)

```js
// when the dom is ready...
$(function() {

    var i = 0;
    
    $("colgroup").each(function() {
    
        i++;
        
        $(this).attr("id", "col"+i);
    
    });
    
    var totalCols = i;
        
    i = 1;

    $("td").each(function() {
    
        $(this).attr("rel", "col"+i);
        
        i++;
        
        if (i > totalCols) { i = 1; }
    
    });

    $("td").hover(function() {
    
        $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
        var curCol = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#"+curCol).addClass("hover");
    
    }, function() {
    
        $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
        var curCol = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#"+curCol).removeClass("hover");
    
    });

});
```

```css
/*
  CSS-Tricks Example
  by Chris Coyier
  http://css-tricks.com
*/

*     { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body    { font: 14px Georgia, serif; }

#page-wrap      { width: 600px; *margin: 0 auto; }

table               { 
border-collapse: collapse; 
width: 100%; 
margin-top: 109px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;}
td                  { border: 1px solid #E0E0E0; padding: 25px; }

thead               { width: 100%; position: relative; height: 109px; top: 0;
                      }

       table th {
  padding: 20px 3px 20px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fafafa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: #ededed;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed, #ebebeb);
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.slim               { width: 88px; }
.hover              { background-color: #eee; }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 
 <title>Fixed Table Header</title>
 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vizitkimsk.com/js/jquery.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

 <div id="page-wrap">
 
    <table>
    
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>

    
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Тираж
      Наименование </th>
            <th>100 шт.</th>
            <th>1000 шт.</th>
            <th>2000 шт.</th>
            <th>5000 шт.</th>
            <th>10 000 шт.</th>
            <th>20 000 шт.</th>
            <th>RUB</th>
           
        </tr>
     </thead>
    
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><b>ОДНОСТОРОННЯЯ</b><br>Визитная карточка <br>90 мм х 50 мм<br><b>4+0</b></td>
       <td>450</td>
       <td>750</td>
       <td>1250</td>
       <td>2600</td>
       <td>4600</td>
       <td>8200</td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><b>ДВУХСТОРОННЯЯ</b><br>Визитная карточка <br>90 мм х 50 мм<br><b>4+4</b></td>
       <td>600</td>
       <td>850</td>
       <td>1300</td>
       <td>3100</td>
       <td>5500</td>
       <td>9500</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>ДВУХСТОРОННЯЯ<br><i>Матовая ламинация</i></td>
       <td>+250</td>
       <td>+800</td>
       <td>+1100</td>
       <td>+2600</td>
       <td>+4800</td>
       <td>+7000</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><i>Скругление углов</i></td>
       <td>+250</td>
       <td>+250</td>
       <td>+400</td>
       <td>+800</td>
       <td>+1400</td>
       <td>+2000</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>ОДНОСТОРОННЯЯ<br><i>Глянцевая ламинация</i></td>
       <td>+250</td>
       <td>+600</td>
       <td>+900</td>
       <td>+2000</td>
       <td>+3900</td>
       <td>+6000</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      
     </tbody>
    </table>
      
 </div>

 
 
 
 Вторая таблица
 
 
 
 
  
  
   <div id="page-wrap">
 
    <table>
    
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
        <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>

    
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Тираж
      Наименование </th>
            <th>100 шт.</th>
            <th>1000 шт.</th>
            <th>2000 шт.</th>
            <th>5000 шт.</th>
            <th>10 000 шт.</th>
            <th>20 000 шт.</th>
            <th>RUB</th>
           
        </tr>
     </thead>
    
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><b>ОДНОСТОРОННЯЯ</b><br>Визитная карточка <br>90 мм х 50 мм<br><b>4+0</b></td>
       <td>450</td>
       <td>750</td>
       <td>1250</td>
       <td>2600</td>
       <td>4600</td>
       <td>8200</td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><b>ДВУХСТОРОННЯЯ</b><br>Визитная карточка <br>90 мм х 50 мм<br><b>4+4</b></td>
       <td>600</td>
       <td>850</td>
       <td>1300</td>
       <td>3100</td>
       <td>5500</td>
       <td>9500</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>ДВУХСТОРОННЯЯ<br><i>Матовая ламинация</i></td>
       <td>+250</td>
       <td>+800</td>
       <td>+1100</td>
       <td>+2600</td>
       <td>+4800</td>
       <td>+7000</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><i>Скругление углов</i></td>
       <td>+250</td>
       <td>+250</td>
       <td>+400</td>
       <td>+800</td>
       <td>+1400</td>
       <td>+2000</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>ОДНОСТОРОННЯЯ<br><i>Глянцевая ламинация</i></td>
       <td>+250</td>
       <td>+600</td>
       <td>+900</td>
       <td>+2000</td>
       <td>+3900</td>
       <td>+6000</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
      </tr>
      
     </tbody>
    </table>
      
 </div>
 
 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий код покраски накрест:

```
$("td:not(:first-child)").hover(function() {

    $(this).parent().find('td:not(:first)').css('background', 'red');
    var index = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)) - 1;
    $(this).closest("table").find('tr').find('td:not(:first):eq('+index+')').css('background', 'red');

}).mouseout(function(){
    $("td:not(:first-child)").css('background', null);
});
```

(не уверен будет ли работать ссылка: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jdrbyz))

Comment: спасибо большое Вы меня спасли ! =) код рабочий я уже начал подыскивать другую таблицу думал эту выбрасывать. а тут Вы. Посоветуйте пожалуйста через какие источники вы обучились JS ? с чего начать

Comment: Виталий, это уже другой вопрос...

Comment: Как и Вы на практике и время нужно.

Comment: а можно к Вам еще один подобный вопрос адресовать только теперь не таблици а табы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431594/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-js?noredirect=1#comment445765_431594

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table").on("mouseover","td", function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).parent().addClass('hover').closest("table").find("colgroup:eq("+index+")").addClass('hover');
}).on("mouseleave","td", function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hover').closest("table").find("colgroup:eq("+index+")").removeClass('hover');
});
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ybL1wpmd/ пример

Comment: Не учли что выделяется первый пункт "Тираж Наименование" - как то странно, зачем?