# Два одинаковых таба, на одной странице, работают не корректно из-за JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хотел разместить на одной странице восемь одинаковых табов но после размещены второго секторы который отображают контент перестали работать не пойму в чем дело?
вот ссылка на [Табы (смотреть)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqwRwZ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!-- tabs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vizitkimsk.com/ar/demo-tab.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vizitkimsk.com/ar/component-tab.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

        <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#section-1"><b><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;  ОДНОСТОРОННИЕ</b></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-2"><b><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;  ДВУСТОРОННИЕ</b></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="content">
                <section id="section-1">
```

11111111

```
                <section id="section-2">
```

22222222

```
        <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#section-1"><b><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;  ОДНОСТОРОННИЕ</b></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-2"><b><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;  ДВУСТОРОННИЕ</b></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="content">
                <section id="section-1">
```

3333333

```
                <section id="section-2">
```

4444444

```
                <script src="http://vizitkimsk.com/ar/cbpFWTabs.js"></script>
    <script>
        new CBPFWTabs( document.getElementById( 'tabs' ) );
    </script>
```

Comment: поменяйте id у повторяющихся элементов, id должен быть уникальным на странице, ну и в скрипте тогда нужно будет добавить запуск табов для других id

Comment: помогите пожалуйста это сделать в в js совсем ничего не понимаю =(

Comment: @Виталий если не понимаете - начинайте изучать JS.

Comment: @Виталий, поменять id это не JS, это HTML и его сейчас нужно знать всем (попробуйте попроходить задания тут: https://htmlacademy.ru/), по поводу JS, вижу в вашем коде только одну строчку, если вы напишите id такого вида: tabs1, tabs2 и т.д., то вам нужно будет вызвать 
`new CBPFWTabs( document.getElementById( 'tabs1' ) ); 
new CBPFWTabs( document.getElementById( 'tabs2' ) );`
и т.д.

Comment: буквально пару часов назад мне это дошло)  спасибо за ваш ответ я изменил в id и в js  new CBPFWTabs( document.getElementById( 'tabs' ) ); поменял, ответ оказался настолько простым что аж смешно что я здесь создал статью =)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ. В строке

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
            <nav>
                <ul>
```

Меняем id tabs на tabs1, tabs2 итд. И в скрипте меняем 'tabs' на tabs1,tabs2 итд...

```
<script>
        new CBPFWTabs( document.getElementById( 'tabs' ) );
</script>
```